# align in alignedat enviroment

Tags: align

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document} 
\[
\begin{alignedat}{1}
    &T^{-1}(X)=(AB)^{-1}X\\
    \Leftrightarrow\; &T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
                                1\\1
                            \end{bmatrix}=(AB)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
                                            1\\1
                                        \end{bmatrix}\\
    &=\begin{bmatrix}
                1&2\\
                -2&3
            \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
                                        1\\1
                                    \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{alignedat}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I align the equals signs in row 3?i tried to add `&` and `&&` but them don't work.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to recommend that you employ a single `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
T^{-1}(X)
  &= (AB)^{-1}X\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad
T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}
  &= (AB)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}\\
  &= \begin{bmatrix} 1&2 \\ -2&3  \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
     %\times %% do you really need this visual crutch?
     \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank sir, I have some change in code. can you help me to solve it?

Comment: Sorry. I think the lengths of the left hand side in rows 1 and 2 were accidentally equal so I didn't express my problem. But I appreciate your support. I found the solution to the problem and I will post it now.

Comment: I think I'll put the question back to the way it was for now.

Answer (score 3):

In `amsmath`'s environments to align equations (`align`, `aligned`, `alignat`, `alignedat`, ...), everything is aligned with respect to `&`'s, or to the end of the line if an `&` is missing. So just place the `&` right before the equal sign on each line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document} 
\[
    \begin{alignedat}{1}
        T^{-1}(X) & = (AB)^{-1}X\\
        \Leftrightarrow T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
                                    1\\1
                                \end{bmatrix} & = (AB)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
                                                1\\1
                                            \end{bmatrix}\\
        &=\begin{bmatrix}
                    1&2\\
                    -2&3
                \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\times\begin{bmatrix}
                                            1\\1
                                        \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{alignedat}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But if left side in row 2, i replace it by ```A```, the left right arrow will don't align. can you any way that can align it?

Comment: @manh3 What would you replace by `A`? And what should the `\leftrightarrow` align with?

Comment: I have some change in code, you can see it above, if i use only one ```&``` before the equal sign the ```\Leftrightarrow``` will not at true position of it. You can try and see it with new code. Thank you